# Counter value for individual table cell

Tags: swift

I want to increase the value of countArray in tableview of first view controller from goButton in second view controller and then make it persist using UserDefaults. following is the code of second view controller

```
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var chartLabel: LineChartView!
//label
var counterValue = float_t()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(counterValue)
    //print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())
}


@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    counterValue = counterValue + 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(counterValue, forKey: "CounterValue")
    counterLabel.text = "\(counterValue)"
}
```

array in first view controller is

```
let countArray = [10,20,30,40]
```

which I've sent to second vc using

```
New.counterValue = float_t(countArray[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the whole array along with the index then

```
arr[index] += 1 
UserDefaults.standard.set(arr,forKey:"AllArr")
```

When you return to the firstVc in `viewWillAppear` re-read it like

```
arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey:"AllArr") as! [Int]
```

Also here you should use an `Int` type

```
var counterValue = 0 // var counterValue:Int! // var counterValue:Int?
```